# difference between the statistical power calculated by statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower.solve_power and the area under the PDF curve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, statsmodels

I am trying to evaluate the [statistical power of a test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_test).
Let's suppose I have two indipendent samples with these properties:

| sample | number of observations | mean | standard deviation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 12 | 2 |

and let's considering a significance level of **0.05**.
I can use [**`statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower.solve_power`**](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower.solve_power.html#statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower.solve_power) to compute the power of this test, but I have to compute the *effect size* and the *pooled standard deviation* (square root of [pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance)).

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.stats.power import TTestIndPower


n1 = 10        # number of observations of sample 1
n2 = 5         # number of observations of sample 2
mi1 = 10       # mean of sample 1
mi2 = 12       # mean of sample 2
sigma1 = 1     # standard deviation of sample 1
sigma2 = 2     # standard deviation of sample 2
alpha = 0.05   # significance level


s_pooled = np.sqrt(((n1 - 1)*sigma1**2 + (n2 - 1)*sigma2**2)/(n1 + n2 - 2))
effect_size = (mi1 - mi2)/s_pooled
ratio = n2/n1
power = TTestIndPower().solve_power(effect_size = effect_size,
                                    power = None,
                                    nobs1 = n1,
                                    ratio = ratio,
                                    alpha = alpha,
                                    alternative = 'smaller')
```

Which gives me a power of: **0.801**.
Now I want to draw a plot of samples probability density functions and related statistical power.By definition, statistical power is the area under the probability density function of the alternative hypothesis (sample 2) starting from the significance level of null hypothesis (consider [this document](https://www.jospt.org/doi/pdf/10.2519/jospt.2001.31.6.307) as a reference).
So I can make a check and compute this area with [**`numpy.trapz`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats


n1 = 10        # number of observations of sample 1
n2 = 5         # number of observations of sample 2
mi1 = 10       # mean of sample 1
mi2 = 12       # mean of sample 2
sigma1 = 1     # standard deviation of sample 1
sigma2 = 2     # standard deviation of sample 2
alpha = 0.05   # significance level


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

s1 = sigma1/np.sqrt(n1)
s2 = sigma2/np.sqrt(n2)

xmin = min(mi1 - 3*sigma1, mi2 - 3*sigma2)
xmax = max(mi1 + 3*sigma1, mi2 + 3*sigma2)
axis_lim = max(np.abs(mi1 - xmax), np.abs(mi1 - xmin))
N = 1000
x = np.linspace(mi1 - axis_lim, mi1 + axis_lim, N)

pdf1 = stats.t(loc = mi1, scale = s1, df = n1).pdf(x)
ax.plot(x, pdf1, color = 'blue', label = 'Sample 1')

pdf2 = stats.t(loc = mi2, scale = s2, df = n2).pdf(x)
ax.plot(x, pdf2, color = 'red', label = 'Sample 2')

limit = mi1 + s1*stats.t.ppf(1 - alpha, df = n1)
filt = x > limit
area_power = np.trapz(pdf2[filt], x[filt])
ax.fill_between(x = x[x > limit], y1 = pdf2[x > limit], color = 'red', alpha = 0.5, label = f'Statistical Power = {area_power:.3f}')
ax.axvline(x = limit, linestyle = '--', color = 'k')

ax.set_xlim(x[0], x[-1])
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.4*max(np.max(pdf1), np.max(pdf2)))

ax.legend(frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

I get:

[image]

Starting from the same values, [**`statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower.solve_power`**](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower.solve_power.html#statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower.solve_power) computes a power of **0.801** while the computed area under the curve is **0.912**.
Where is the mistake? Did I make a mistake in calculating the power or drawing the graphs or both?

Comment: my guess without going through the details, is that in your computation you use scales s1 and s2 for the samples, while the Power computation uses the pooled scale, implicitly assuming that the scale is the same.

Comment: second guess, what you do works for normal but not for t distribution. T-test assuming unequal variance and unequal sample size requires Welch t-test with Satterthwaite df correction. So the exact distribution for the scaled mean difference will differ from the t-distribution with equal variance assumption.

Comment: This is not the way we usually show power, we need one distribution for the test statistic under the null and one under the alternative hypothesis. Here it is just comparing the distribution of the two samples.

Comment: Thank Josef for your help! Starting from data above, how can I derive the distribution for the test statistic under the null hypothesis and under the alternative one?

Comment: you can look at the code for t-test power https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/stats/power.py#L62 The test statistic, scaled mean difference, is distributed as t under the null and non-central t under the alternative.